# samba-tool ldp_wrap open of secrets.ldb

Tags: ubuntu, samba

The title is the message I receive every time I use `samba-tool`:

```
root@DC01:~# samba-tool group list
ldb_wrap open of secrets.ldb
Print Operators
Denied RODC Password Replication Group
Server Operators
...
```

I don't know where that line (`ldb_wrap open of secrets.ldb`) is coming from as I didn't explicitly set a non-standard log level.  Is there any way to get rid of that from my output?

This is on an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS aarch64 server running `samba-tool` 4.11.6.

Comment: What version of Samba is this and on what OS ?

Comment: Thanks @RowlandPenny, I've updated the post to include that information!

Comment: Try adding '-d0' to the end of the command, if that fixes it, add 'log level = 0' to your smb.conf and restart Samba.

Comment: Thanks @RowlandPenny.  I need to keep `log level = 3` in my `smb.conf` for actual logging, but adding `-d0` to the command line works just fine.  Thank you!